# How to pre-process texts to match Googles pre-trained word2vec model?

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am wondering which steps I have to execute on my corpus to pre-process it the same style like google did for their massive, pre-trained word2vec model (https://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/ )

According to the website they did the following:

- bigrams/ trigrams
- removal of some stop words (only common ones like: a, and, of)
- removal of some numbers (only without surrounding letters)

Is there any source which details all steps?

Did they also  e.g. ...

- remove some punctuation
- lowercase some letters
- stem or lemmatize
  ?

Comment: I've not seen any official write-up of how text was preprocessed to create the `GoogleNews` word-vector set. Looking at the words included gives hints – there doesn't appear to have been any stemming/lemmatization, & alt-cased versions of many words indicate little if any case-normalization was applied. The multi-word phrases were likely created by multiple passes of the statistical approach they described around the time of the original word2vec papers - but their stats/corpus isn't available. So, if trying to match them, the list of actual tokens in their file may be the best guide possible.

Comment: Note, though, that the `GoogleNews` vectors are now 6+ years old, from a very large but private-to-Google training set of news articles. For domains other than news articles, or domains with terminology that's evolved a lot in the last 5 years, they may be of limited use. Training your own vectors from fresh/domain-relevant data, or using other more-recent public vector sets, may be more fruitful than trying to reverse-engineer their decisions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your information is very helpful!